# What are some use cases for assignInMyNamespace?

Tags: r, variable-assignment, r-package

I would like to know of some packages that make use of `assignInMyNamespace` and what it's used for, if it is even advisable to use this function in production code. The help page gives the following information:

> `assignInMyNamespace` is intended to be called from functions within a package, and chooses the namespace as the environment of the function calling it.

However it also gives the following warning about `assignInNamespace`:

> `assignInNamespace` should not be used in final code, and will in future throw an error if called from a package. Already certain uses are disallowed.

Presumably this is because packages shouldn't ever try to change the namespaces of **other** packages, which is why the warning doesn't apply to `assignInMyNamespace`. Is this true?

NB: I am developing a package with an unexported testing function that allows any *unexported* function in the package to be temporarily replaced with one that saves its inputs and outputs. I am also considering such a technique for switching between memoised / un-memoised versions of functions.

**EDIT**: In practise, `assignInMyNamespace` only changes *unexported* functions - not 'any function in the package' as previously stated. I only realised this recently, and it's actually thrown a spanner in the works with the package I'm developing. Therefore I would also be very interested to know if there is a solution to the problem that works across both exported and unexported functions during package use.

Comment: Based on a quick [GitHub search](https://github.com/search?q=language%3AR+-extension%3ARd+assignInMyNamespace&type=code), one theme seems to be to use in `.onLoad()` to access some runtime values. But it would definitely be interesting to hear directly from package authors who have used it.

Comment: Thanks for this! As I suspected, most of these uses seem to be workarounds for different problems and are often commented as such. Still very interested to hear from anyone who has made more serious use of this function, but in the meantime I'll keep trawling github.